# re-attach kubernetes retained PVC to existing azure disk

Tags: azure, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

Using Azure CSI driver v1.27.1, Kubernetes v1.23 (no AKS, but via Rancher engine RKE)

We "retain" all our PVCs, I can see azure disk is still here after the PVC/PV have been deleted. This is OK.

But now, when the same PVC/PV is created again, it creates a new azure disk instead of using the existing disk!

How can I re-use the existing disk?

(I believed this was automatic, by using PVC namespace/labels).

I can manually "attach" to an existing disk, but syntax is not handy:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-reclaim
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
    - external-attacher/disk-csi-azure-com
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: test-reclaim
  storageClassName: azure-disk-retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  csi:
    driver: disk.csi.azure.com
    volumeHandle: /subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg-XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/pvc-XXXXXX
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-reclaim
spec:
  storageClassName: azure-disk-retain
  volumeName: test-reclaim
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score -1):

***You can make use of below yml code in order to re use the existing azure disk.***

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: disk.csi.azure.com
  name: pv-azuredisk
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: managed-csi
  csi:
    driver: disk.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: /subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/MC_myAKSCluster_myAKSCluster_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myAKSDisk
    volumeAttributes:
      fsType: ext4
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-azuredisk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  volumeName: pv-azuredisk
  storageClassName: managed-csi
```

I applied it in my Kubernetes:-

```bash
kubectl apply -f pvc.yml
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks you, I am doing this but looking for an automatic way

Comment: @ThomasDecaux did you find a automatic way?

Comment: no :-/ this drive me nuts